# Resistor between stand alone atmega 328 and Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino

I have a stand alone atmega328 and an Arduino Nano. I want the Nano to digital read one digital outputs from the stand alone atmega328. Do I need a Resistor? If yes, how many ohms?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note, there is a dedicated StackExchange site for electronics questions, here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

if your Arduino Nano and your Atmega328 are powered by the same power supply, you will be able to connect 328's output to the nano's input without any kind of trouble (no resistor, just the wire or trace). If they're not powered by the same power supply you should connect their grounds together.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need any. Both ATmega328 and Arduino Nano have internal pull-up resistors, it's the matter of the GPIO configuration.

Some links:

- [Arduino digital pins](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins)
- [ATmega328 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf) (check paragraph 13.2)

NB: As *mamodom* pointed out, you need to share ground between two of your boards.